# Vista Startup Repair cannot repair my Toshiba Laptop (L300D)

Tags: boot, windows-vista, laptop-repair

I installed some updates, and now the computer doesn't boot up, it just keep's telling me to go to repair, which doesn't fix the problem.

I see the BSOD on startup, but it flashes by too quick.  (I also don't have Vista on DVD to do a reinstall if I need to)

This is what I get from the Startup Repair details

Problem Event Name       StartupRepair V2
Problem Signature 01:    External Media
Problem Signature 02:    6.0.6001.18000.6.0.6001.18000
Problem Signature 03:    2
Problem Signature 04:    131074
Problem Signature 05:    BadDriver
Problem Signature 06:    NoBootFailure
Problem Signature 07:    0
Problem Signature 08:    0
Problem Signature 09:    unknown
Problem Signature 10:    1168
OS Version:              6.0.6001.2.1.0.256.1
Local ID:                1033

Answer (score 2):

Immediately after switching on your computer, keep tapping the F8 key.  This should bring up the boot menu.

One of the options should say "**[Last known good configuration](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Using-Last-Known-Good-Configuration)**".  Highlight it using your up and down arrows and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

This *should* let you boot back into Windows.

Failing this, I would try a **[System Restore](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/tutorial142.html)** back to a time and date before the updates were installed.  You should also have this option while you are within Startup Repair utility.  If you do not, you could always download a [**Vista Recovery Disk**](http://neosmart.net/blog/2008/windows-vista-recovery-disc-download/), burn it to DVD and boot into it.

Answer (score 2):

As for the re-installing Vista part, Im pretty sure that model of Toshiba has a recovery partition. If you do find that you need to re-install, use this method to get to it:

- Turn off laptop
- Hold down number 0
- Turn laptop back on, while still holding number 0
- Hold number 0 until you see it booting into the recovery partition.

This is how I did it on my L500, and a quick google revealed that it is the same for the L300.